# how can i show ajax-loading when i fetching some information from database?

Tags: ajax, jquery

i used `jQuery` with `Ajax` By this code it works fine

```
$.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost/msite/index.php/site/ajax',
                data : catdata,
                success : function (msg){
                    $('body').html(msg);
                }
                });
```

but i want to show the ajax-loading `gif` while fetching that information from database?

And , is that way `secure` Or i have to add some security to it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by secure? You're posting over HTTP, so everything you send is in plain text, so it isn't secure.

Comment: @James Allen : So how can i make that secure

Comment: You need to use HTTPS, which will require the purchase of a certificate. When you contact a website using HTTPS rather than HTTP, everything sent is encrypted in both directions. Here's a link with further information: [HTTP Secure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure). Hope that helps

Comment: @James Allen : Thank u 4 help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body').html("<img src='spin.gif' />").fadeIn(100, function () {
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/msite/index.php/site/ajax',
    data: catdata,
    success: function (msg) {
        $('body').html(msg);
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make your database query synchronous on the server then your Ajax will be spinning as long as the request is being processes, including a database query and server request/response roundtrip.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to do this yourself within the jQuery. Create a hidden image on the page, call .show() just before calling the ajax command and be sure to call .hide() inside the `complete` event...

```
complete: function () {
    $("#ticker").hide();
}
```

You can download a suitable image from [ajaxload.info](http://ajaxload.info/).

Comment: How can i create a hidden image!

Comment: To be honest, I would use Shyju's solution as it's neater than mine, but here's the answer to your question: <img src='spin.gif' style='display:none;' />